# Ruby process forking / threading - child process lifetime

Tags: ruby, multithreading, process, fork

I main function with a basic loop inside it. I want to fire off a child process for every iteration of the loop (that goes off doing an HTTP request, more on that later).

If I am using processes, my problem is that it looks like each child process continues the execution of the main thread, whereas I want only the main process to go on after the loop, and the children to die after the HTTP req is finished. Main process is not interested in each child to finish before continuing.

Looks something like this now:

```
data.each do |k, v|
  (pid = fork) ? Process.detach(pid) : doHttpQuery(v + ":" + "k")
end
# code after this comment should only get executed once
```

Also, when the processes finish, I get this

```
thread.rb:189:in `sleep': deadlock detected (fatal)
```

If I use threads like this

```
threads << Thread.new { doHttpQuery(v + ":" + "k")}
```

and then

```
threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

The threads are fired, but for some reason it is not actually doing the HTTP request, and the whole process just comes to a halt.

Comment: In the threading version is `doHttpQuery` getting called at all?

Comment: I restructured the code a bit, and yes, the HTTP query was called (through httparty gem). It just seemed to get to a halt, but it was actually waiting for all the HTTP calls to finish, so that just shows how 'green' the threading is. Still having the issue with forking

Answer (score 0):

The child process must call `exit` or `exit!` to stop executing:

```
data.each do |k, v|
  if pid = fork
    Process.detach(pid)
    doHttpQuery(v + ":" + "k")
    exit
  end
end
```

The difference between `exit` and `exit!` is

- `exit` runs `at_exit` functions.  Its default exit code is 0.
- `exit!` does not run `at_exit` functions.  Its default exit code is 1.